# React Native: Phone number not updating and continuing to give error message

Tags: react-native

I have a bug in my application where I am trying to update a phone number and when I click on save, I get the error message and the original phone number stays populated:

[image]

Obviously, something has gone wrong with validation. I was hoping it was perhaps the regex although it has a solid one, but I changed it like so:

```
const regex = {
  userName: /^[-.\sa-zA-Z]+$/,
  cardName: /^[-\sa-zA-Z]+$/,
  password: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&*()\-+!\\.]?).{8,}$/,
  zip: /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/,
  memberId: /^\d+$/,
  // phoneNumber: /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/,
  phoneNumber: /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im,
  email: /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,
};
```

That did not help.

I am thinking it has to be the validation function, but I am staring at this thing and I can't see anything that sticks out:

```
_validate = props => {

    const validationErrors = {
      businessName: props.businessName ? '' : 'Is Required',
      businessPhoneNumber:
        props.businessPhoneNumber.length === 0 ||
        regex.phoneNumber.test(props.businessPhoneNumber)
          ? ''
          : 'Phone number must be valid and contain 10 digits',
    };
    const isValid = Object.keys(validationErrors).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (validationErrors[curr] !== '') {
        return false;
      }

      return acc;
    }, true);

    this.setState({validationErrors, displayErrors: !isValid});
    return isValid;
  };
```

### Update

I tried the solution in the below answer, but unfortunately that did not work.

Here is whats going on:

When I add the phone number and save it, it is in `props` here:

`_validate = props => {` and you can see that here:

```
{screenProps: undefined, navigation: {…}, businessName: "Ceramic Tile Distributors", businessWebsite: "", businessPhoneNumber: "8667073945", …}
```

but then it ceases to exist in the `validationErrors` object here:

```
const validationErrors = {
      businessName: props.businessName ? "" : "Is Required",
      businessPhoneNumber:
        props.businessPhoneNumber.length === 0 ||
        regex.phoneNumber.test(props.businessPhoneNumber)
          ? ""
          : "Phone number must be valid and contain 10 digits"
    };
```

and you can see that here:

```
{businessName: "", businessPhoneNumber: ""}
```

Why its re-rendering with the above as empty strings I do not know.

I can tell you that this here:

```
const isValid = Object.keys(validationErrors).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      console.log("On line 84 of BusinessDetails: ", isValid);
      if (validationErrors[acc] !== "") {
        return false;
      }

      return acc;
    }, true);
```

returns `undefined`, but why I do not know.

`_validate` is being used inside the `_saveChanges` function like so:

```
_saveChanges = () => {
    const isValid = this._validate(this.props);

    if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ displaySpinner: true });
      this.props
        .updateInformation()
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ displaySpinner: false }, () => {
            this.props.navigation.goBack();
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          Alert.alert(
            "Error",
            this.props.businessPhoneNumber.length === 0
              ? "Please provide a business phone number. If your business phone number no longer exists, please call 1-800-NFIB-NOW to have this information deleted."
              : "We couldn't save your changes. Please try again.",
            [
              {
                text: "OK",
                onPress: () => this.setState({ displaySpinner: false })
              }
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          );
        });
    }
  };
```

I can tell you that `const isValid = this._validate(this.props);` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

When I test your code, it looks like there is no problem with your regex.  But the below line is not  correct

```
  if (validationErrors[curr] !== '') {
    return false;
  }
```

You should use `acc` to get the values. consider the below code

```
  if (validationErrors[acc] !== '') {
    return false;
  }
```

However, I can't run your code in my system. `.reduce` not working here. As  a workaround, you can use below code

```
  _validate = props => {

    const validationErrors = {
      businessName: props.businessName ? '' : 'Is Required',
      businessPhoneNumber:
        props.businessPhoneNumber.length === 0 ||
        regex.phoneNumber.test(props.businessPhoneNumber)
          ? ''
          : 'Phone number must be valid and contain 10 digits',
    };
    let isValid = true
    Object.keys(validationErrors).map((acc, curr) => {  
      if (validationErrors[acc] !== '') {
       isValid= false
      }

    });

    this.setState({validationErrors, displayErrors: !isValid});
    return isValid;
  };
```

Comment: I would like to say that your code works, but above I have updated what is going on, perhaps you can help me still. thank you in advance.

Comment: @Daniel you are updating the phone number in `props`. Never so that. Use `state` instead of props. like this  `this.setState({businessName: "", businessPhoneNumber: ""});` . Or could you please tell me where did you calling this function.  _validate(props)?

Comment: that is still not saving it, I get the same exact behavior, but above I answer your question of where I am calling `_validate`.

Comment: I am able to get it to save, but it does not persist, when I logout and log back in, the saved phone number is no longer there. I did not use your solution by the way as `isValid` is already declared.